# Disable react native classes on pressing a different class in the same group

Tags: class, react-native, touchablehighlight

I am completely new to react, Using TouchableHighlight, I have created a class,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
export default class ChooseProComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            marginRight: this.props.mr,
            borderRadius: 3,
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            borderWidth: 0.7,
            borderColor: "#e1e1e1",
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 8 }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 26,
                height: 26
              }}
              source={this.props.typeImage}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 13,
                alignSelf: "center",
                marginLeft: 8,
                color: "#737f8d"
              }}
            >
              {this.props.type}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

I have imported ChooseProComp class in a different component like this, I am not sure whether I have to add a custom method.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 6 }}>
            <ChooseProComp
              mr={7}
              typeImage={require("../../../Images/homescreen/typeicons/medical/medical.png")}
              type="Medical"
              onPress={() => this.renderType("Medical")
            }
            />

            <ChooseProComp
              typeImage={require("../../../Images/homescreen/typeicons/dental/dental.png")}
              type="Dental"
              onPress={() => this.renderType("Dental")}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 6 }}>
            <ChooseProComp
              mr={7}
              typeImage={require("../../../Images/homescreen/typeicons/homiopathi/homia.png")}
              type="Homeopathy"
              onPress={() => this.renderType("Homeopathy")}
            />

            <ChooseProComp
              typeImage={require("../../../Images/homescreen/typeicons/ayurveda/ayurveda.png")}
              type="Ayurveda"
              onPress={() => this.renderType("Ayurveda")}
            />
          </View>
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 6, marginBottom: 25 }}
          >
            <ChooseProComp
              mr={7}
              typeImage={require("../../../Images/homescreen/typeicons/yoga/yoga.png")}
              type="Yogic science"
              onPress={() => this.renderType("Yogic science")}
            />

            <ChooseProComp
              typeImage={require("../../../Images/homescreen/typeicons/unani/unani.png")}
              type="Unani"
              onPress={() => this.renderType("Unani")}
            />
          </View>
```

So when I select a particular type, like Medical, I want to disable the ChooseProComp classes of other types. Please help me with this. Other types opacity needs to be decreased as well.

Comment: What does 'disable' mean? That you can't select them anymore?

Comment: yes, I do not want the user to select other types when one type is selected

Comment: Ok, so I think you can handle an array of 'disabled' values in the main component, pass a disabled prop to each child and use it in TouchableHighlight (since it supports it)

Comment: I did not understand, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I will try to make an example

Comment: That would help a lot! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you just want one item (`<ChooseProComp>`) to be selected, I suggest you to simply handle the selected one in your main component state, which at the beginning will be undefined:

```
state = {
  selected: undefined
};
```

Then define onPress function of each `<ChooseProComp>` like:

```
  onPress={() => {
    this.renderType("Medical"); // I don't know how this works so I won't modify it
    if(!this.state.selected){ // if the state is undefined, then set it!
      this.setState({
        selected: "Medical"
      })
    }
  }
```

Then, again for each `<ChooseProComp>` pass a prop `disabled` like:

```
<ChooseProComp
  ...
  disabled={this.state.selected && this.state.selected !== 'Medical'}
/>
```

So, in `<ChooseProComp>` component (class) you can use it in `<TouchableHighlight>`:

```
  <TouchableHighlight
    underlayColor="transparent"
    onPress={this.props.onPress}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    disabled={this.props.disabled}
  >
```

Let me know if this fits your question, or I've misunderstood, or it's not clear enough!

Comment: Great! it worked! I just need to add opacity for the disabled elements. If done, I will get what I had in my mind! Thanks a lot!

Comment: any good practice to add opacity to the disabled elements?? let me know!

Comment: Can you explain better or provide an image of your request?

Comment: here it is, If I select a profession Medical, other options are getting disabled. Now I want the disabled options opacity to be 0.5 and the select option to be 1.

Comment: I think you just answered yourself. Simply add `style={{ flex: 1, opacity: this.props.disabled ? 0.5 : 1}}` to your `<TouchableHighlight>`

Comment: I did this, just wanted to know if there are any other methods of doing it! Thanks again!

Comment: Uhm, I personally don't know. You can obtain a similar behavior changing colors of background, texts and other elements.. but it's more verbose I think

Comment: Hey, I have an issue now, let's say I select Medical, rest of the options will be disabled and I save my details. If I visit my homepage and come back to edit my profile, everything will be enabled again. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is not an easy question to answer about. As you know, react works like this: you changed screen and the component unmounted, so when you called it again it mounted another instance, which is new in all.
1) Simplest solution: pass a prop to the new screen and repass it when you call the previous screen again. This is not a good practice, but you can do it if your case is simple.
2) Hardest (& better) solution: using Redux library: it provides something like a store to update everytime you want and from which you can read info you've saved.
3) Other: save your type to asyncStorage

Comment: Okay! I will look into it!